# Auto populate a field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to have a similar function as vlookup in excel. so in as basic language as possible. When a client enters a value in my case a disease like Asthma LMB040, I would like it to look for the diagnoses in another table and auto populate the next column.

How would I code this is SQL 2008 R2

Comment: `select diagnoses from another_table where disease = 'Asthma LMB040'`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL 2008 R2

Comment: To answer you properly we need to know the structures of the tables involved. The very basic is like the comment of @VR46 but for you case it may need some JOINs to do so.

Comment: Use a (probably LEFT OUTER) JOIN like this: `SELECT <fields> FROM <baseTable> LEFT OUTER JOIN <lookupTable> on <lookupTable>.<KeyValue> = <baseTable>.<lookupValue>`. Next, read a basic SQL book